# Advice on networking career

Tags: networking

I need some insights on a networking career. I have a valid CCNA and few months of experience as a Jr. network analyst. My focus is a type of job where I can administer networking/storage hardware and possibly managing servers/workstations too. I am new to this job area, specifically new to city like LA. I am currently unemployed and so, my question is: should I continue with my cisco certifications(routing/wireless) or other comptia certs or both to get a reliable job? I am really interested in CCNA wireless but watching craigslist(LA) and other job sites, it seems people need more cisco voice people. While, some others also ask for Net+ certs. I have scarce financial sources so, its better to make some good decisions. I have not been applying yet due to some personal problems but I will soon.

Thank you!

P.S.
I don't know if I can ask questions like this here. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're on the right path with a CCNA.   A CCNP would be a valid longer-term goal, but without the experience to back it up it won't get you very far.

CCVP (voice) or CCNA-Wireless are also reasonable pursuits, however I wouldn't recommend following them until you have more general network experience under your belt.

In my opinion a Net+ certification is worthless; I wouldn't waste resources pursing that type of education or certification.

Look for jobs in "Network Operations" in particular.  They often provide a good foot-in-the-door opportunity for someone looking to break in to the field.  You may have to take second or third shift in these areas, but the experience and upward mobility are excellent.

All of the above advice applies to a job in Network Engineering.   If you're looking to get in to a more "jack of all trades" field (servers,workstations,network,and SAN) I'm afraid I don't have much advice - other than to note that typically these type of jobs only exist at smaller companies.   Larger companies almost always break out infrastructure role responsibility in each of the 4 areas.

Comment: i dont think i would be jack of all trades kinda guy. definitely in to network engineering. i will look up for those jobs for sure. i now have some clear idea on how to make those decisions. thank you so much! really appreciate your interest